# C++ Factory and Linker dependencies

Tags: c++, dependencies, factory

My library includes an interface (representing a camera) and a few derived classes.
Each derived is implemented to specific HW, which leads each derived class to depend on external vendor libraries.

- Each derived class is a static library and links its library dependencies
- I only supply one class named `Factory`, which has one method:
  `ICamera* create(const std::string& type)`
- The factory #includes and links all derived classes, and library users aren't aware of the derived impls. `create()` is implemented naively:

  `if (type == "a") return new CameraA();`
  `if (type == "b") return new CameraB();`
  `...`

So basically there is one bloated Factory.lib that includes all necessary dependencies, and library users can create any camera impl by just linking to Factory.lib

**Questions**

1. When you link to Factory.lib, you need all dll's from all vendors when running your application. Ideally I would want you to only need the dll for the specific camera you are using. Is there a way to achieve this?
2. I'm considering compiling each derived as a dll and not lib. Now Factory.lib is not bloated, and all camera specific dependencies are in each derived dll. If I don't solve `li` #1, this doesn't help much, because you will still need all derived dll's in addition to Factory.lib and vendor dll's.
3. Is there a better way to implement the Creator class (or method) ? My derived classes are a limited number, 5-6, and don't grow often.
4. Any other tips to minimize dependencies and improve design are welcome

Comment: Dlls can be [Delay Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx). I've never done this, so I don't know if it suits your needs (hence making this a comment rather than answer), but it might remove the need for having all Dlls available.

Answer (score 3):

You can load the shared library (or dll) at runtime. You have to have a clue to where (in which dll) to look for the specific ICamera implementation. You can for example export a second function per dll that gives exactly the information, what implementations (type=="a" and type=="c") are provided by a specific dll. When starting the application, it can search for the dlls and call that information interface for every dll.